# ReplaceAll Regex: Update group before Replacing

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex to extract some values in groups and put those values into another section of my new string but I need to make another change to a captured group before the replaceAll executes, I have this code:

```
String regex = "<button data-key=\"([^\"]*)([^<]*)</button>";

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String newStr = strLine.replaceAll(regex, "<button data-key=\"$1$2<span>&#x$1</span></button>");

    }
```

This works OK extracting the **data-key** (Group1 / $1) value into span tag when value is simple (no "-" in it), but when data-key is i.e. 1f1e8-1f1e6 the value is extracted like this: &#x1f1e8-1f1e6, so I was thinking if it's possible to do something like this:

```
String newStr = 
    strLine.replaceAll(regex, 
        "<button data-key=\"$1$2<span>&#x" + "$1".replaceAll("-", "&#x") + "</span></button>");
```

replace "-" -> "&#x" for $1 in the replaceAll function but no success so far, do I need to change to Matchers? or any help on best approach for this scenario would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit1:

*CURRENT*:

```
<button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8"><span>&#x1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8</span></button><button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e9"><span>&#x1f1e8-1f1e9</span></button>
```

*EXPECTED*:

```
<button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8"><span>&#x1f1e8&#x1f1e8&#x1f1e8</span></button><button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e9"><span>&#x1f1e8&#x1f1e9</span></button>
```

Edit2:
INPUT:

```
<button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8"></button>
<button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e9"></button>
```

Edit3:
WHOLE INPUT:

```
<div>
<h3>GG</h3>
 <div class="ep-categoryItems">
 <button class="ep-item" data-key="1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8" title="Grinning face" style="background-image: url('${cdn}/images/emoji/f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8.png');"></button>
 <button class="ep-item" data-key="1f1e8-1f1e9" title="Grinning face" style="background-image: url('${cdn}/images/emoji/1f1e8-1f1e9.png');"></button>
 </div>
<div
```

Comment: Please show example(s) of input/output, i.e. what `strLine` is before the replace call, and what you expect the value of `newStr` to be after the replace call. Also show what the actual result is, so we can see how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: Added expected example

Comment: You are aware that CURRENT and EXPECTED are not valid XML/HTML, right?

Comment: Do you want to fix the content of `<span>` by itself, or do you want to replace the content with fixed value from `data-key` attribute? Seems to be the latter, just asking to be sure.

Comment: I added the input, those are the button tags with out the spans yet, and btw I'm just showing portion of my INPUT but the values inside SPAN are emojis values so the browser will render OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** Changed to work in Java 8 and with new input.
Also fixed to add the missing `;`

It can be done like this:

```
String input = "<button data-key=\"1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8\"></button><button data-key=\"1f1e8-1f1e9\"> TO BE REPLACED </button>";

String regex = "(<button data-key=\"([^\"]+)\">).*?</button>";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(buf, m.group(1) + "<span>" + m.group(2).replaceAll("-?([0-9a-fA-F]+)", "&#x$1;") + "</span></button>");
String output = m.appendTail(buf).toString();

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

```html
<button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8"></button><button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e9"> TO BE REPLACED </button>
<button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8"><span>&#x1f1e8;&#x1f1e8;&#x1f1e8;</span></button><button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e9"><span>&#x1f1e8;&#x1f1e9;</span></button>
```

Comment: let me check, it's just that my INPUT doesn't have the spans yet I'm inserting those with the data-key value inside (group1)-> <button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e8-1f1e8"></button>
<button data-key="1f1e8-1f1e9"></button>

Comment: btw I'm using java8. but matchers maybe have no big changes

Comment: how would you do it for the whole INPUT I added? basically, other tags wrapping the <buttons> and other properties for the <buttons>